# Programmatically set tax in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am calculating the tax for the entire order using a third party API.
*How can set total tax rate to a quote ?*
`$quote->setTax($taxAmount);` is not working.
can anybody please help ?

Comment: Magento has a complex tax tier/calculation system in place for you to use. If you'd like to completely ignore it, you can disable it in the Magento admin and write a custom module (using observers) to handle tax.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353374/82482

Answer (score 0):

That's how you should do it:

Change the file app/code/Vendor/Package/etc/di.xml in your custom package by adding the line

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart" type="Vendor\Package\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Create the plugin

```
app/code/Vendor/Package/Model/Checkout/Cart/Plugin.php
```

Now, add the content to the file above:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Checkout\Cart;

class Plugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $quote;

    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        # Do something, here for instance, it remove TAX for giftvouchers
        if ($productInfo->getTypeId() == 'giftvoucher') {
            $productInfo->setTaxClassId(0);
        }

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```